# Count Number of Values Passed Into a Haskell Constructor

Tags: haskell

Suppose I have a data type

```
data Foo = Foo String Bool | Bar (String->Bool)
```

I want a function  f that does:

```
f (Foo _ _) = [String, Bool]
f (Bar _) = [String->Bool]
```

In particular, I'd like this function to magically know that Foo and Boo are constructors, and not give me either of

```
f (Foo _ _)  = [String -> Bool] -- #Don't want this!!!!
f (Boo _)  = [String, Bool] -- #Don't want this!!!!
```

How can  I do this? I know that I can print a list of records of an ADT using Data.Data, but I can't figure out how to print a list of typenames.

---

(If this is not possible, I would settle for a  function f' that takes in ADTs and outputs whether or not it has 0 parameters.

```
f'(Foo _ _) = False
f'(Bar _) = False
```

I want this to work even if I don't assign records to the ADT f' operates on.)

Comment: well can you write down the **type-signature** of your `f`? Aside form the typo (it's `[(String,Bool)]` I guess) - your cases seem to have different types which is a problem

Comment: I really have trouble with understanding your request - is `f'` a function from any type to `Int`? ... as in `f' :: a -> Int`? or is it `f' :: Foo -> Int` (you basically wrote down this function already)

Comment: I imagined

    f :: (Data a) => a -> [TypeRep] (or something like that)

and f' :: (Data a) => a -> Bool. (I changed my request).

Comment: ok something similar might be possible - have a look at [Generics](https://wiki.haskell.org/GHC.Generics) - but that's real deep stuff ^^

Comment: I doubt very much that you'll be able to get anything as powerful as a `TypeRep` out of any generic programming package, but something simpler you probably can. Counting shouldn't be too terrible with `GHC.Generics`.

Comment: This seems like a strange request, possibly indicative of a design error. Some more context would help us suggest an alternative approach: what are you really trying to do?

Comment: Turns out this was a design error. I was basically trying to take an instance of any ADT, modify every Foo used in its constructor (recursively) by some  function Foo->Foo that I passed in, while leaving all other fields the same. This could be accomplished by recursively applying gmapT.

I'm kind of curious why the recursive gmapT isn't in the Data.Data library, since it seems to be straightforward and also quite useful.